# I need to make my buttons interact with Javascript for this etch-a-sketch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get my buttons to work as they say via Javascript. I can't seem to come up with a function to clear the grid and start a new game(which would allow the program to ask the user to enter a new size that they would want to make the grid, bring it back to the default size(16x16), or change the color from black. Lastly, why is that I can't seem to change the height of the table. I can change the width but the table goes all the way to the bottom of the screen. Is there a way to compress it into a square.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/bklynbest/6f68qodf/4/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var t = $('<table/>'),
    r = $('<tr/>'),
    x = 16,
    y = 16;
  for (var i = 1; i <= (x * y); ++i) {
    if (i % y === 0 && t.append(r)) r = $('<tr/>');
    r.append($('<td/>'));
  }
  $('body').append(t);
  $('td').hover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "black");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
table {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
h1 {
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: red;
  font-family: Cursive;
  color: yellow;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>
<title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>

<body>
  <h1 align="center"> My Etch-a-Sketch game</h1>

  <div class="navbar">
    <button class="normal">Default</button>
    <button class="random">Random Color</button>
    <button class="opacity">Opacity Color</button>
    <button class="clear">New Game/Clear</button>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your buttons functions? Or you need help to write them?

Comment: I need help writing them. I've tried but I am VERY unfamiliar with Javascript.

Comment: Please do jsfiddle so i can help you.

Comment: I would suggest starting here: http://learn.jquery.com/, or specifically on the events page: http://learn.jquery.com/events/

Comment: I added the jsfiddle file. And also jquery I think understand well enough to work the way I want it to for this project. Its the javascript portion that I need help with. But thanks for the site I'll check it out though since I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your jsFiddle here : http://fiddle.jshell.net/6f68qodf/7/

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var colours = ["red", "blue", "green", "purple", "black", "white"];
    var colour = "black";
    var t = $('<table/>'),
        r = $('<tr/>'),
        x = 16,
        y = 16;
    for (var i = 1; i <= (x * y); ++i) {
        if (i % y === 0 && t.append(r)) r = $('<tr/>');
        r.append($('<td/>'));
    }
    $('body').append(t);
    $('td').hover(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", colour);
    });

    $('.clear').on('click', function () {
        $('td').css("background-color", "grey");
    });

    $('.random').on('click', function () {
        colour = colours[Math.floor((Math.random() * colours.length))];
        console.log(colour);
    });

    $('.normal').on('click', function () {
        colour = "black";
    });

});
```

I haven't coded the opacity button because I'm not sure what you would like to do with that :). But personally a `canvas` would be a much better bet for this then a `table`, I hope my code will help.

Comment: Thanks alot!! What exactly is a canvas though in this instance?

Comment: A HTML5 `canvas` can be used to draw shapes, images, text well. its a Canvas you can paint on :) here is a few tutorials http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-element/ just navigate though on the left

Answer (score 0):

To get buttons to run JavaScript, you need to add an event listener for the "click" event to each of of your `<button>` elements. You can do this a few ways, here are two simple ones:

1) Use the `onclick` attribute on your button elements. Here is a quick example:

```js
function buttonClicked(){
  alert("Button was clicked!");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="buttonClicked()">My Button</button>
```

2) Create an event listener for the button click:

```js
var myButton = document.getElementById("my_button");
myButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  alert("You clicked my button!");
});
```

```html
<button id="my_button">My Button</button>
```

Here is [a link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) to more information on click events.

As for your issue with height, you set `height: 100vmin;` on your table in your CSS. That is equivalent of saying, "Set the height of my `<table>` to be 100% the size of which ever is smaller, the window's height or width." If you really want to use `vmin`, here is [a link](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) with some good information. Otherwise, you should probably use a different CSS unit for the height of your table. See here for a [list of CSS units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

Comment: Thanks that site was/is very helpful.